# How to use retranslateUi() recursively on all ui in QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt5, locale, qwidget, qtranslator

In my Qt5 application I am trying to switch the language at run-time.
So far here my simple function:

```
QTranslator _translator;

void MainWindow::switchLanguage(QString lang)
{
    if (!_translator.isEmpty()) qApp->removeTranslator(&_translator);
    if (lang == "it")
    {
        _translator.load("Language_it_IT.qm", qApp->applicationDirPath());
        qApp->installTranslator(&_translator);
    }
    ui->retranslateUi(this);
}
```

It works fine, but for the `MainWindow` only. Inside I have some form classes (with their UIs) that I load into a `QStackedWidget`:

```
FormMonitor _formMonitor;    // they all inherit from QWidget
FormSettings _formSettings;  // and have their .ui file
FormProgram _formProgram;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // ...
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(&_formMonitor);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(&_formSettings);
    ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(&_formProgram);


    // ...
}

void MainWindow::loadView(int index)
{
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(index);
}
```

These forms are not translated.

**How can I translate all the "nested" forms inside my `MainWindow`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimplement the `changeEvent` of your form classes like this:

```
void Form::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange)
        ui->retranslateUi(this);

    QWidget::changeEvent(e);
}
```